# How to define a squiggle range for the problem matcher in tasks.json (VS Code)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have written a `problemMatcher` in `tasks.json` that looks like this:

```
"problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "myFileExtension",
    "pattern": {
    "regexp": "myRegExp",
    "file": 1,
    "line": 2,
    "severity": 3,
    "message": 4,
    "location": 2
    }
}
```

I am using this problem matcher to squiggle the lines that have problems after I run my build task. However, instead of squiggling the whole line, I would like to squiggle a particular range, based on where the problem actually comes from. After reading the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), I am still not sure how this can be done.

How can I squiggle a range in `tasks.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See last example in the doc.

The location can be 1, 2 or 4 numbers enclosed in `()`

- 1: `(line)`
- 2: `(line,char)`
- 4: `(lineStart,charStart,lineEnd,charEnd)`

````
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "watch",
      "command": "tsc",
      "args": ["--watch"],
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "fileLocation": "relative",
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^([^\\s].*)\\((\\d+|\\d+,\\d+|\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+)\\):\\s+(error|warning|info)\\s+(TS\\d+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$",
          "file": 1,
          "location": 2,
          "severity": 3,
          "code": 4,
          "message": 5
        },
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": "^\\s*\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}(?: AM| PM)? - File change detected\\. Starting incremental compilation\\.\\.\\.",
          "endsPattern": "^\\s*\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}(?: AM| PM)? - Compilation complete\\. Watching for file changes\\."
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}```
````